# Label gets selected on clicking enter key in the tabulator cell

Tags: tabulator

I have a [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amv93/vy7Lg3a2/5/) to show the issue that I am facing.
Tabulator 'email' column has freetext set to true to allow the user to set the value of the cell to a free text entry as follows:

```
editorParams:{
        values:{
          "steve@boberson.com":"steve",
          "bob@jimmerson.com":"bob",
          "jim@stevenson.com":"jim",
          "harvy@david.com":"Harvy",
          "ken@thompson.com":"Ken",
          "denny@beckham.com":"Denny"
                 }, 
      freetext:true,
      searchFunc:function(term, values){ 
      console.log("term and val "+term +" \n"+values);
            var matchedEntries = {};
            var matchFound = false;
            for(var key in values) {
                if(key.includes(term)){
                  matchFound = true;
                  matchedEntries[key] = values[key];
                }
             }         
            if(matchFound){
                  return matchedEntries;
            }
            else{
               return {term: term};
            }
         } 
       }}
```

1. Select one of the values from the selector list displayed, say steve, value being 'steve@bobberson.com'.
2. Then after the value is selected, click on the same tabulator cell, the value displayed suddenly changes to the label.When user clicks enter key now, the label is selected instead of the value,.ie.        steve will be displayed instead of steve@bobberson.com

If this is not a bug, how do I make sure that the value steve@bobberson.com remains selected after clicking enter. This is because freetext option is set to true in the editorParams of the column
Attached a gif showing the issue[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not a bug,

With ***freetext*** enabled, users are able to enter any text they like in that field and it will be saved which is exactly what is happening in the example

If they select the email address again from the list then it is correctly saved.

It is an either/or scenario, you can either restrict the users to selecting specific values from the list OR you can allow them freetext in which case anything goes.

If you want a different behaviour then you can always build a custom editor that works in the way you want. Checkout the [Custom Editor Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/edit#edit-custom) for more information

Comment: Agreed that it is an either or or scenario,but the behavior here is when we click on already assigned cell and press the enter key, the label is taken as value instead of the value itself. Shouldn't the value be selected instead of label?